# How to remap an index signature to make keys detectable in IDE

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, index-signature

So, I'm trying to create an object that can have dynamic attributes, but I want that the IDE can be able to detect the keys that I'm already gave to this object.

if I try this example:

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
}


type dynamicObject = { [key: string]: Person }

const maria: dynamicObject = {
    maria: {
        name: "Maria",
        age: 37
    }
}
```

If I use `maria.` to try to detect the keys from the object `maria` the IDE will not show me anything.

I know that using generic types I can workaround this problem using `[P in keyof T]`

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
}

interface Panel<T> {
    label: string
    fields: (keyof T)[]
}

interface Field<T> {
    label: string
    value: T
}

interface Form<T> {
    panels: { [key : string] : Panel<T> } 
    fields: { [P in keyof T]?: Field<T[P]> }
}

const form: Form<Person> = {
    panels: {
        main: {
            label: "Panel",
            fields: ["name", "age"]
        }
    },
    fields: {
        name: {
            label: "Name",
            value: "Test"
        }
    }
}

form.panels // not detecting panel keys
form.fields // detecting fields keys
```

In the example above I'm able to detect the keys from `form.fields` because I'm using a type with pre-defined keys. But my goal is to be able to transform this Form type into the same thing but with the possibility of detecting the keys from the `form.fields`

So, there is any function, remap type, or way to transform this index signature into string literals to accomplish this?

I know that this is possible because there are libraries like *stiches.io* where you create an object with custom variants and the function generates a new object with the custom keys being detectable by the IDE. I tried to see the magic behind that but the typing is over complicated to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with only a type, there needs to be a function with an infered return type (that's what stitches is also doing).

```
export type Form = { <T>(values?: U): U }

declare const buildForm: Form;

const form = buildForm({
    panels: {
        main: {
            label: "Panel",
            fields: ["name", "age"]
        }
    },
    fields: {
        name: {
            label: "Name",
            value: "Test"
        }
    }
})

form.panels // OK
form.fields // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBi0C2cC8cDecAPAKoB8AFAG4CGANgK7ADOA-AFxwkCUnJcAXwBQQgCbAAxnRpRUEiADtm8AEYMAlnVEYomTjswBuEfKXwAZllxw1m7Vgr4hcF3DA0FwOs05PX-uEwadQVfZwCI6RUvTgAiAAUPL1iAGnCI-3N1L1EfOABtWIUaTGBUuFiaAHMygF10gOF-ATTM7K08vwzi0rCMgKiYioA5ErLW-tdaRmA4gBUWGFiG5obhAW4RS10AOndPbzgAeiO4AHkAaSFtzB2snOZj08ugA)

Comment: ty, this function helps a lot.